# Custom toolbar using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, custom-controls, toolbar

I wanna develop a custom toolbar with some sorts of CRUD functionality using asp.net. The problem is that it needs to have an option to dynamically connect any table for any databases for sql server.

How can it be possible?

Here is my idea :

when user places the tollbar on the page, it shows options to provide server and user credentialas, then it shows all DB , when user select a DB it shows all the tables and so on ...

Comment: *"How can it be possible?"* And what the connecting database table gonna do with toolbar?? You need to explain what are you trying to do and what you done so far, so that others can help!!!

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I am thinking like this
when user places the tollbar on the page, it shows options to provide  server and user credentialas, then it shoes DB name , when user select a DB it shows all the tables and so on ....